# Ibid doesn't show up

Tags: bibtex

I modified an essay layout for my purposes and everything is hunkydory except for the fact that my chicago style citations will spam the footnotes when citing consecutively from the same work. I assumed it would do Ibid but it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\title{\textsc{foobar}}
\author{\textsc{Mr.Foobar}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\rhead{\textsc{Mr.Foobar}}
\lhead{\textsc{foo}}
\linespread{1.6} % Line spacing
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,nonamebreak]{natbib}
\begin{document}

Body goes here\footnote{\cite{BibtexKey1} p.##}

even more body text \footnote{\cite{BibtexKey1} p.##+x}


\newpage
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{cites}
\end{document}
```

Illustrated:

[image]

UPDATE: I have installed biber and biblatex with biblatex-chicago. Can someone show me a MWE for superscript citations featuring ibid? I got as far as eliminated the repetitions but after the first one I just get the number and a period.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't think `chicago.bst` does "ibidem".

Comment: Would you be willing to use `biblatex` instead of BibTeX? Using the former, the solution to your problem is rather trivial.

Comment: `chicago.bst` implements the Chicago guidelines from 1992.  Is that really what you want/require?  If you want current (15th or 16th ed.) Chicago Manual of Style, you should use `biblatex-chicago` (which also requires you to have the `biblatex` package installed).  Note also that `biblatex-chicago`'s author-date style requires the use of `biber` instead of `BibTeX`.  --- All are very easy to install nowadays.

Comment: I'll try this tonight, sounds promising. I am new to TeX and so unfamiliar with all the packages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the behaviour seen is 'by design', but 'solved' by updating to a more modern solution as indicated in comments.

Comment: I think the underlying matter of the question is very valid and certainly fits in the [scope of TeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So  I've edited the question heavily and hope that it now does get reopened.